# I failed to install pip in windows

Tags: python

**when I install pip in windows,there is following problem:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

**Then I install setuptools ,there is following problem:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
    import setuptools
  File "C:\Users\Jeffrey\Desktop\setuptools-35.0.2\setuptools\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from six.moves import filter, map
ImportError: No module named six.moves
```

**what should I do next?**

Comment: Can you post your installation commands too?